# Replace zeros in matrix in R with element from row below

Tags: r, matrix, replace, zero

I have a matrix and it looks like this:

```
 > sc_matrix
      sc_start sc_end
 [1,]      227      0
 [2,]        0    235
 [3,]      272    279
 [4,]      298      0
 [5,]        0    306
 [6,]      353      0
 [7,]        0      0
 [8,]        0      0
 [9,]        0      0
[10,]        0      0
[11,]        0      0
[12,]        0      0
[13,]        0    387
```

There are 1862 rows in total.

For both columns separately, I would like to get rid of the zeros. Specifically, each time a zero gets deleted the element below jumps one row up. For example, the `0` in `sc_matrix[2,1]` gets deleted and `272` from `sc_matrix[3,1]` takes its place. Likewise, the `0` in `sc_matrix[1,2]` gets deleted and `235` from `sc_matrix[2,2]` takes its place. This should be done individually for `sc_start` and `sc_end` so that in the end the matrix looks like the following:

```
     sc_start sc_end
[1,]      227    235
[2,]      272    279
[3,]      298    306
[4,]      353    387
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: What happens if number of `0` in columns is different?

Comment: Numbers `==0`, as well as numbers `!=0` is equal for both columns. The total length of both columns is equal accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(
        sc_start = c(227,0,272,298,0,353,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        sc_end = c(0,235,279,0,306,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,387)
      )
df2 <- data.frame(
          sc_start = c(df$sc_start[!df$sc_start==0]),
          sc_end = c(df$sc_end[!df$sc_end==0])
       )
```

This works only if, removing zeros, the length of both series is equal.

Comment: Yep that works. Length is equal. See also my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
# get a matrix of zeros of equal dimension
sc_matrix_2 <- 0 * sc_matrix

len <- rep(0, times=ncol(sc_matrix))

for(i in 1:ncol(sc_matrix))
{
    # get nonzero elements in order
    sc0 <- sc_matrix[,i]
    sc0 <- sc0[sc0 != 0]

    # count of nonzero elements
    len[i] <- length(sc0)

    sc_matrix_2[1:length(sc0),i] <- sc0
}

# cut off unnecessary zeros
sc_matrix_2 <- sc_matrix_2[1:max(len),]
```

This takes column by column, deletes zeros and creates a matrix from those. If the number of nonzero items in each column differs, the output number of rows is the maximum of nonzero elements. Unused cells are filled with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which would work if you are certain that the matrix would collapse down with both columns having the same size:

```
col1 <- as.numeric(m[m[, 1] != 0, 1])
col2 <- as.numeric(m[m[, 2] != 0, 2])
matrix(c(col1, col2), nrow=length(col1), ncol=2)
```

### Demo

If the assumption about both columns having the same height after removing zeroes be incorrect, then we could try padding to make them the same length, and then go with a similar approach to above.